# Semantic of Unicode symbols?

Tags: unicode, semantics, symbols

I wonder if the semantic of [Unicode symbols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_symbols) is defined?

Think of `☺`. What does this symbol *mean*? I see that it is a smiling face. I know that it is named "WHITE SMILING FACE". But what should it be used for? When not to use it? Why is it part of Unicode at all?

Would you consider `Hi! ☺` as being equivalent to `Hi! :-)`, `Hi! :)`, and/or `Hi! (:`?

Is there a semantic difference between `☺` and `☻`? Why is there only a white frowning face (`☹`), not a black one?

Think of [playing card symbols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Playing_Cards_%28Unicode_block%29). If I'd write about a great hand I had in a game, *may* (not "should") I say "I had a ♠ 9" instead of "I had a spade 9"?

Think of all the other "icon-like" symbols: `☃`, `☀`, `☂`, `☘`, `❤` (different to playing card symbol `♥`), `✂`, `☎`, `ℹ`, `☯`, …

I read that `⚓` (name: "ANCHOR") was added for use in maps. But the name doesn't reflect that it should be used only (or even: at all) for this case.

Comment: It's an interesting question, but I doubt it is on-topic here. Maybe http://superuser.com/ is better place for it, since currently your question is more related to general usage of PCs rather than programming.

Comment: @aland: I thought about the right place. I'm coming from a semantic markup (HTML) perspective; I wonder when to use this symbols on webpages and webapps. But I'm not looking for usability or common sense, but a theoretical/technical definition (in the Unicode specification), so I thought SO this would be the right place.

Comment: Unicode aims to define and map every "symbol" (be it a writing glyph or otherwise) to a code-point. The meaning of a symbol is irrelevant and should be determined by context.

Comment: @Dai: Could you elaborate on this in more detail? This poses questions like: Why is there no smiling face with a nose, glasses or hair? One could consider that the specific font could add those details. But there would be the risk that in the future the consortium might decide that it is a separate symbol per se and add a smiling face with nose. And why is the same smiling face, one in black and one in white, considered to have *different* code-points?

Comment: @unor - I think you are thinking about this too much. I think a lot of those symbols were included in Unicode merely because they were present in commonly used fonts.

Comment: @unor They might do that, or they'd use Unicode ligatures and define "empty face" and separate "nose" and "smile" or "frown" symbols which the author then has to combine themselves. I'm personally opposed to the addition of many symbols to Unicode because for what should be obvious reasons.

Comment: Could get interesting for the Unicode [woman with bunny ears](http://shapecatcher.com/unicode_info/128111.html): 

Comment: Look at the fonts that support the [while frowning face](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2639/index.htm) and the [white smiling face](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/263a/index.htm). The frowning face is not supported by the same fonts as the smiling face which means it was added later and only for specific fonts, the black frowning face was never added it seems.